# String concatenation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am having difficulties concatenating strings in TypeScript.

Code:

```
var info= {user:'med'};
console.log('le nom est:${info.user}');
```

The result is:

> le nom est:${info.user}

How do I concatenate 2 strings in TypeScript?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With a [template string](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings):

```
console.log(`The name is: ${info.user}`);
```